# Apache Not Showing Folders and Directories

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I was studying [PHP Connection Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php), then I used a script , without much understanding it. 
 i.e.

```
<?php
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(); // optional
ob_start();
echo ('Text the user will see');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush();            // Unless both are called !
// Do processing here
sleep(30);
echo('Text user will never see');
?>
```

Which Leads to this, [see img](http://s11.postimg.org/5lyshqlk3/2014_07_25_132050_1366x768_scrot.png).
i.e. Localhost is not showing any files and directories. When I try some other link, in the directory, it shows File Not Found.

I Searched but no such issue is near to it. Also I can't find much about connections header in php.

Also I tried, 
1. To restart Apache2. :FAILED
2. Reinstall whole lamp-server :FAILED
3. Completely remove lamp-server then Installed Again : FAILED

I'll be grateful if someone can come up with working solution.

```
System : Lubunutu + Apache2
```

Comment: Anyone! My serve is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the config files. Odds are you probably edited it somehow and its not matching the normal files. Btw, your script has nothing to do with the problem you're facing.

In most case directory got changed, in my case it was, /var/www/html.
Just edit the file 000-default.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Replace /var/www/html to /var/www.

Comment: Thanks A Lot, bro. I wish I could upvote your Answer.